# Diffetence between enable_if usages

Tags: c++11, sfinae, enable-if

As cppreference indicates:

std::enable_if can be used as an additional function argument (not applicable to operator overloads), as a return type (not applicable to constructors and destructors), or as a class template or function template parameter.

Is that because it doesn't make any difference where exactly enable_if is used in a template class or template function - the only thing that matters is the fact that it IS used in a template class or template function (and will remove an instantiation from an overload resolution set)?

Could it be also used this way for example

```
template<typename T>
class X {
public:
    void someFunc() {
        enable_if<is_integral<T>::value, int>::type dummy;
    }
};
```

to achieve the same effect as when being used as cppreference indicates?

Comment: For SFINAE to work, the "substitution failure" must occur in the function declaration, not in its implementation. The point of the exercise is to have overload resolution skip over this function in favor of another overload; but overload resolution doesn't look inside the function's body.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! But if use enable_if in the function declaration, for example as an additional funnction parameter (with a default value) then we can call this function with that additional parameter, right? To leverage enable_if we've introduced additional fictive parameter?

Comment: That's one way to do it, yes; it's not the only way. In any case, if the extra parameter is the way you choose to go, one technique is to have a single public function forward to an overloaded set of private functions, and use SFINAE on those. For these private functions, it's harmless to add extra parameters or whatever, since you control the call site.

Comment: I'd like to read a little more about it, how can I find something, could you provide some keywords for googling or a link?